# How to escape spaces in Apache SetEnvIf value

Tags: apache-2.2, environment-variables

I am trying to use SetEnvIf (Apache2, via a .htaccess file) to store an environment variable where the value to be assigned to the variable needs to contain spaces. For example, trying to set environment variable "AUTH_KEY" to have value "a b":

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/example" AUTH_KEY="a\ b"
```

No matter what I do, I have not been able to escape the space in the value - the space acts as a delimiter between env vars to be created (in the above AUTH_KEY is created with value '"a\' and a second env var is created called 'b"'). I have tried single-quotes too with no luck.

How do I escape the space character?

Comment: This is a terrible shot in the dark and I don't even expect it to work. What happens if you URLencode the space? (i.e. use %25 in place of one) Yes, I know this isn't a URL and I don't expect it to be treated like one.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, in the end I figured out how to add spaces without having to use escaping (it works for me at least). I found that placing the quotes around the key=value, rather than just the value was the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I figured it out for myself…

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/example" "AUTH_KEY=a b"
```

… which looks odd, but works. It correctly sets AUTH_KEY to value `a b`

Hopefully this might save someone else's time in the future.

**The details:-** I am not a C programmer, but bumbling around on Google I found mod_setenvif.c listed at http://www.bvbcode.com/code/s6148jvr-385031

A function is called on line 405 (`ap_getword_conf`, for which I found detail at http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/apache_mod/155.htm) which seems to parse strings, delimited by whitespace (but optionally encapsulated in quotes and accepting the use of escape characters).

I noticed that this happened before the sub-string returned by the function above being split by the '=' character (line 411, by function ap_getword). Thus quotes around the `key=value` pair, rather than just the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using instead `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/example" AUTH_KEY="a\sb"`. \s here represents the space.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that after you posted but still no luck (the variable value gets set as _"a\sb"_ (i.e. \s does not get replaced).

Comment: Also worth noting is that the quote marks are included in the value - they seem to be part of the value itself. Thanks

Comment: Try using a[\s]b. Looking forward to your results.

Comment: Still no luck, `a[\s]b` is set as the value as-is. Thanks for the thought though.